# Setting AJAX URL for custom module

Tags: module, javascript, magento-1, url, ajax

I have a JavaScript file in /js/mds/mds_collivery.js. In it I have an AJAX call that should go to magento_install_url/collivery/ajax/cptypes. It will only be used in /checkout/onepage/.

However, if I set the URL to be:

```
url : "/collivery/ajax/cptypes",
```

it tries to access

```
http://localhost/collivery/ajax/cptypes
```

and if I set the URL to:

```
url : "collivery/ajax/cptypes",
```

it tries to access

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/checkout/onepage/collivery/ajax/cptypes
```

I currently hard coded it to

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/collivery/ajax/cptypes
```

but this isn't ideal as the setup procedure for my module would require users to edit this file before it can work.

Is there a JS variable or another way to get the Magento Install Location inside JavaScript?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to get a Magento Base URL into a .js file. If its only going to be used in one area, the following should work:

url : "../../collivery/ajax/cptypes",

One thought. When working with Magento locally, you should **always** make it as a subdomain (like www.magento.localhost), else you will run into cookie issues. In fact, Magento won't install without it being in a subdomain. If you setup Magento as a subdomain, your first answer, url : "/collivery/ajax/cptypes", would work.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I don't think I have enough rep to upvote your answer yet. So sorry about that.
I'm assuming the best solution is then to use ../../ instead of just /? This is already a huge step forward in the right direction, can't believe I didn't think of this! So thanks. :)

Comment: @kab8609 The ../../ works perfectly! Going to use that for the time being.

Answer (score 11):

in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/checkout/onepage.phtml` add this code somewhere at the top of the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseUrl = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('');?>';
</script>
```

now you should be able to use in your js file this:

```
url : baseUrl + "/collivery/ajax/cptypes",
```

Actually you can add the script anywhere in the template (header, footer, ...) just make sure it's in the page you need. Since the checkout page is the only one you need, I suggested adding it in the onepage template.

Comment: Awesome! But, how do plugins usually do this? I mean, there has to be a "right" way of doing this?

Comment: Oh, and I seem to require 15 rep to upvote an answer. If you and @kab8609 upvotes my question, I could upvote your answers as I do believe in giving credit where credit is due. :)

Comment: I learn something new everyday. Good catch!

Comment: The right way if doing this I think it is to pass the base url (or full URL) to your js function that does the ajax request.

Comment: Why not putting the full url into the `getUrl` call? Then if you change the frontname, the link is still correct. `Mage::getUrl('collivery/ajax/cptype')`

Answer (score -1):

you can get your base URL as

```
var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
```

and then use an ajax call as

```
url : baseUrl + "/collivery/ajax/cptypes",
```