# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] path issue in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Whats the right way of giving $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] path.

**UPDATED:**

Ie) In my **app\design\frontend\base\default\template\folder\index.php** i need to call other config files which is in document root of magento.

```
  <?php
    // Show only compile error
    error_reporting(E_COMPILE_ERROR );
    // check if pdo library enabled ? 
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/magento/test/ajax_table.class.php');
    $obj = new ajax_table();
    $records = $obj->getRecords();
  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <script>
        ...
   </script>
 </head>
</html>
```

**var\www\html\magento\test\ajax_table.class.php**

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/magento/test/config.php'); 
class ajax_table {
..
 }
```

If i include the above:

```
<?php
// Show only compile error
error_reporting(E_COMPILE_ERROR );
// check if pdo library enabled ? 
require_once('/test/ajax_table.class.php');
$obj = new ajax_table();
$records = $obj->getRecords();
?>
```

UPDATED:

Also path mismatch here:

**\magento\skin\frontend\rwd\default\js\test\script.js**

```
ajax = function (params,action){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "ajax.php",    //ajax.php is in var\www\html\magento\test\ajax.php
    data : params+"&action="+action,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
    ...}
```

I get blank screen with controller error...

Table insertion/ other operation is happening if i keep my index.php in same var\www\html\magento\test folder.

Its path issue.

The file seems to get called when i echo inside it, but functionality is not as expected, which works if i keep index.php too in the root folder, but i want it in design folder

Comment: How you are calling this file in url ` app\design\frontend\base\default\template\folder\index.php `. I think it's wrong folder structure according to magento and magento code not allowed here.

Comment: where have i specified in url for index.php?   im calling index.php from layout

Answer (score 2):

I think `magento` in main folder so you can add easily add it like. try this and let me know

```
 $includePath = Mage::getBaseDir(). "/test/config.php";
    require_once( $includePath);
```

Comment: @SachinS updated the code...

Comment: How about the path in url: in .js file??

Comment: `url: "<?php echo Mage::getBaseDir() ?>ajax.php", ` if is located with same directory with `index.php`

Comment: ajax.php is in magento root folder and index.php is in design template folder

Comment: nope i am talking magento default `index.php` like last time you asked the question.

Comment: I have placed the ajax.php in magentos default root where index.php is...i get 404 not found :  %3C?php%20echo%20Mage::getBaseDir()%20?%3Eajax.php"

Comment: either give the complete url in script.js like 'http:://localhost/ajax,php' or create the hidden file and get value from their in js you get the two option use any on these

Comment: I tried complete url and also  this   url: baseUrl + "test/ajax.php",  for this i get 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: now it is going right place but your code have error kindly check that.

Comment: Ok thanks..working...fixed from this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3565/setting-ajax-url-for-custom-module

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like this :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/test/ajax_table.class.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('test/ajax_table.class.php');
require_once ($path);
```

and in `ajax_table.class.php` use this

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('test/config.php');
require_once ($path);
```

Comment: Invalid dir type requested: test/ajax_table.class.php

Comment: @SachinS Is 'magento' your root directory and all magento files installed in this folder ?

Comment: yes magento is the root